# Relay with NodeMCU is not working

Tags: nodemcu, relay, iot, home-automation

I'm using a Relay Channel and NodeMCU(8266-WIFI). When i trigger the connection, LED Turns ON in Node MCU But the Relay connection is not working. I'm not sure what is the issue, Please help to fix it..

My Pin connection as follows.

> 1. NodeMCU (VIN) -> Relay (VCC)
> 2. NodeMCU (G) -> Relay (G)
> 3. NodeMCU (D1) -> Relay (IN4)

My code as follows,

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>  
#include <FirebaseCloudMessaging.h>
#include <Firebase.h>
#include <FirebaseHttpClient.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#include <FirebaseError.h>
#include <FirebaseObject.h>


// Set these to run example.  
#define FIREBASE_HOST "xxx-xxxx.firebaseio.com"  
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "xxxxxx"  
#define WIFI_SSID "xxxx"  
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "xxxxx"  
  
void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  
  // connect to wifi.  
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);  
  Serial.print("connecting");  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {  
    Serial.print(".");  
    delay(500);  
  }  
  Serial.println();  
  Serial.print("connected: ");  
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  

  pinMode(D1, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); 
  
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH); 
  Firebase.set("LED_STATUS",0);  
}  
  
int n = 0;  
 
void loop() {  
  // Get value  
  n=Firebase.getInt("LED_STATUS");  
 
  if (n==1) {  
     digitalWrite(D1, LOW); 
     digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); 
     Serial.print("LED is ON ");   
     Serial.println(Firebase.getInt("LED_STATUS"));   
     delay(1000);  
  }  
 else{  
   //LED_BUILTIN
   digitalWrite(D1, HIGH); 
   digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); 
   Serial.print("LED is OFF ");   
   Serial.println(Firebase.getInt("LED_STATUS")); 
   delay(1000); 
 }  
 
}
```

[image: Connection PICTURE]

Comment: the red wire is not connected to anything

Comment: you mean the Main power Red wire right ?I removed the connection to take photo..

Comment: What version of the NodeMCU is that?

Comment: On back of board it mentioned, "Node MCU V3"
and in front top right corner , ver 0.1

Comment: Does the relay work when you connect IN4 to Vcc ?

Comment: No. That is the problem, When i trigger the power, the relay port is not closing and light bulb is not getting power

Comment: Can the relay module work with 3.3V logic signal?

Comment: If you attach and detach IN4 to VCC on the NodeMCU, does the relay click when you attach it? If it doesn't, and you still have VCC on the relay board connected to VIN(5V) on the NodeMCU, and GND on the relay board connected to GND on the NodeMCU, something is wrong with either your wiring or the board. Try another IN on the board and see if one is faulty. Those modules will work fine with 3v3 control signal coming from the NodeMCU due to the opto-isolator on the inputs of the relay board. If it does click, something is wrong with your code.

Comment: @chris could you explain a bit more please. I'm a very beginner. i bought a 5v relay board, but i'm not sure what output nodeMCU provides, I hope it is same 5v ?

Comment: @peter-feerick : Click ? U mean a click sound will come when i connect IN4 to vcc on NodeMCU ?

Comment: But VCC is connected to VIN right ?

Comment: @GaneshKumar Yes, a click sound from the relay, as it is a electro-mechanical switch, hence you should hear when it activates/deactivates. The yellow jumper to the side connects the VCC used to power the relays to the VCC used for the rest of the electronics on the module. The jumper is there because sometimes you don't have enough power, so you pull that jumper off, and use a second power source. If you put a GND or a VCC signal to one of the IN pins, that relay should either turn on or off.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the 3V isn't enough to power the relay.
https://www.instructables.com/Getting-Started-With-ESP8266LiLon-NodeMCU-V3Flashi/ shows the board supplies USB power (pin VU).

You can remove the jumper that connects signal voltage to relay power and connect the relay board to the USB power.

After that change I could turn the relays on and off, but I could not reliably power 4 relays, 2 relays as shown below seems fine.

[image]